# É melhor trabalhar com min-width ou max-width em layout no CSS?

Tags: css

Estou criando alguns protótipo de site responsivo. Mas oque notei é que quando uso `min-width` ou `max-width` eles fazem quase a mesma coisa, apesar deles determinar uma largura minima e uma máxima continuo achando que fazem mesma coisa a alguma diferença entre os dois para poder usar nos layout.

Comment: Sabe qual é a diferença dos conceitos de "mínimo" e "máximo"?

Comment: min-width:100px, o elemento vai ter no mínimo 100px de largura, mas pode ter mais dependo do conteúdo que estiver dentro. max-width:100px, se não houver conteúdo dentro do elemento ele fica com 0px de largura, mas se vc colocar algo dentro ele vai crescer até no máximo 100px.... Sobre a responsividade de cada um e como usa-los no @media veja as duplicadas. Tb recomendo que leia sobre *Mobile First* https://www.todoespacoonline.com/w/2015/03/como-escrever-seu-css-para-projetos-mobile-first/

Comment: Obrigado, pela resposta valeu